# Kazam crashes with segfault

Tags: 17.10, kazam

I have installed Kazam (version 1.4.5) on Ubuntu 17.10 and I can't start it. When I try to run from command line I get this messages:

```
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~$ kazam 
/usr/bin/kazam:32: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/frontend/window_area.py:30: PyGIWarning: Wnck was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gdk, Wnck, GdkX11
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/gstreamer.py:35: PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/frontend/indicator.py:148: PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import AppIndicator3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/frontend/indicator.py:97: PyGIWarning: Keybinder was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Keybinder', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Keybinder
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

System log:

```
Jan  2 15:12:01 wiktor-papu kernel: [19123.519166] kazam[27887]: segfault at 42 ip 00007f637f4bbad4 sp 00007ffe8cfb3ea0 error 6 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f637f429000+134000]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

It seems to be a problem with Wayland.

If you start the session and choose Ubuntu on Xorg then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't worry, your system is fine**. 
This is not a bug of Ubuntu itself, just follow my instructions to correct the problem.
A `segfault` happens when the program writes to a forbidden memory sector and the system kills it immediately with the `SEGV` signal. This is a bug in *Kazam Screencaster* (caused probably by an outdated implementation of the graphical interface) and only its developers can offer the right support: report your bug using the [official bug-tracker (click here and hit 'Report a bug')](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam) and they will help you. ;-)
Other users are reporting crashes after a `SIGSEGV`, you won't be alone.

The developers may also suggest methods to avoid the problem until the bug is corrected.
After the bug is corrected and the new version (or a patch for the latest version) of the software is released, you'll only need to update Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

...and the software will work.

Have a nice day.

---

<sup>If you need further support use the comments under this answer and I'll help you. To say 'thank you' just upvote and star.</sup>

Comment: I know what a segfault is, I'm a programmer and my voyage through C has given me enough of these ;) I was just thinking that someone might have come across something similar.

Comment: @gonczor answers are meant to help *any* user with the same problem. This is not StackOverflow, here good solutions should be also easy to understand for everyone. That's why I make efforts to use simple words, thats all. :-)